# Scheduled posts appear as clickable in the front end

Tags: posts

My Wordpress is giving me the weirdest of errors. When I schedule a post, it gets published, but if you visit the post and click on a paragraph as a visitor, it becomes "editable".

A blue border appears after the click surrounding the paragraph, and you can write and change things, although you can not save them if you are not admin (or, at least, I hope so).

When the post is published immediately, the behavior is perfectly normal, you can not click and edit anything. Pages behave normally too.

I deactivated every plugin and tested other themes, but the error always appears.

My host provider said that it could be because of the php version, so they downgraded from 7.1 to 5.6, but the error remains.

If someone has some tip, it would be greatly appreciated. If I find the solution I will edit this, because I can not find anything related on the web.

Thanks, best regards.

Comment: Where did you get the theme? Have you contacted the theme developer?

Comment: Hi:

The theme is Newspaper, by Tagdiv. I've tested other themes and they also give me the error, so I did not contact them. Also, I deactivated plugins, updated, etc, but no avail, the error keeps happening.
Regards.